# notifyDataSetChanged() is not working in MVP android

Tags: android

I have a refresh button which gets the updated list of items. Refresh button is on the fragment header on click of this I update the adapter.

Adapter code inside Fragment(FragmentView)

```
 @Override
    public void setList(List<Entity> List, LangAdapter.OnlangClickedListener listener) {
        langAdapter = new LangAdapter(getContext(), langList, listener);

        rvLang.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        rvLang.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(rvLang.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        rvLang.setAdapter(langAdapter);
        langAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

My code inside Fragment onClick inside Fragment(FragmentView)

```
 presenter.onLanguageAutoRenewClicked();
```

Inside Presenter this is the implementation

```
public void onLanguageAutoRenewClicked() {

// Retrofit call
onResponseSuccess() {

                   FragmentView.reloadData();
}

}
```

and from here inside my FragmentView I have reloadData

```
 @Override
    public void reloadData() {


               langAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
```

I am calling a WS on click of button which is giving me the new list items which I am calling reloadData and on the fragment class I am setting notifyDataSetChanged but still I am not able to update the items in the adapter.

Comment: you don't need to use this: langAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
because you tried to set a new Adapter to RecyclerView.
Check your loaded list.

Comment: How did you update `langList` inside fragment?

Comment: Update of list happened in fragment presenter not in the fragment @Md.Asaduzzaman

Comment: Changes should reflect in `langList`. Can you check by debugging the `langList` is updated inside `reloadData` before call `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: Yes list has updated value but fragment adapter is still holding the old values

Comment: You have a languagesAdapter and a langAdapter, is this correct?

Comment: It's typo mistake I edited it @BruceWayne

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman how to update the language adapter that's my point

Comment: @HamedRahimvand list is updated but how to pass the updated list to adapter since we can not create the new adapter

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> [list is updated but how to pass the updated list to adapter since we can not create the new adapter – Vish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60276678/notifydatasetchanged-is-not-working-in-mvp-android?noredirect=1#comment106622628_60276678)

I think your problem is the list that passed to the adapter. To call notify's methods, you should update the list that passed to the adapter.

You can implement your adapter like below with DiffUtil to increase the simplicity of the manipulation.

This code developed by Kotlin language. If you need it with Java, I can rewrite it for you :)

With DiffUtil you don't need to call notifyDataSetChanged() or other notify methods anymore.

```
class FooRvAdapter(
    private val dataList: ArrayList<Fee>
      ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    fun updateItems(newDataList: List<Fee>) {
        val diffCallback = FooRvAdapterDiffCallback(dataList, newDataList)
        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback, false)
        dataList.clear()
        dataList.addAll(newDataList)
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this@FooRvAdapter)
    }

     /*
      OnBind(),ViewHolder, etc.
      ...
     */



    inner class FooRvAdapterDiffCallback(
        private val oldList: List<Fee>,
        private val newList: List<Fee>
    ) : DiffUtil.Callback() {

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) =
            newList[newItemPosition].id == oldList[oldItemPosition].id

        override fun getOldListSize() = oldList.size

        override fun getNewListSize() = newList.size

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) =
            newList[newItemPosition] == oldList[oldItemPosition]
    }

    interface FooCallBack {
        fun onItemClick(data: Fee)
    }
}
```